# How do I script chntpw wizard

Tags: command-line

I am using SystemRescueCd to reset passwords on laptops I need to fix for work. SystemRescueCd supports autostart scripts http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Run_your_own_scripts_with_autorun

The issue I'm having is with chntpw, which uses a type of "command line wizard" that requires me to send a command, then press 1 {Enter}, then press y {Enter}. I'm stuck at how to send the 1 and the y to the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, for sending `1`, `y`, `q`, and `q` again:

```
chntpw -i SAM <<< $'1\ny\nq\nq'
```

`\n` to simulate hitting enter.
`q` to quit the current menu

You will have to adapt the `chntpw` command to get what you need.